# How to access the JSON file that stores all user info?

Tags: html, json, database, web

Hi I am trying to create a web app and I require to scrape the information from this website..

https://getbiib.com/events/104

I would like to access the JSON API that contains all the runners(4347 entries) from this webpage. But I could only get the JSON file of what is displayed in front of me only. Here is an example of the JSON URL I only managed to obtain.

https://getbiib.com/events/104/individual_rank.json?category_type_id=44&draw=1&columns%5B0%5D%5Bdata%5D=rank&columns%5B0%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B0%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B0%5D%5Borderable%5D=false&columns%5B0%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B0%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B1%5D%5Bdata%5D=display_name&columns%5B1%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B1%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B1%5D%5Borderable%5D=false&columns%5B1%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B1%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B2%5D%5Bdata%5D=steps_count&columns%5B2%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B2%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B2%5D%5Borderable%5D=false&columns%5B2%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B2%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&start=0&length=100&search%5Bvalue%5D=&search%5Bregex%5D=false&_=1626617902103

Comment: so what is your question? And what did you try before asking here?

Answer (score 0):

Just change the `length` parameter value from `100` to `5000 or more` and it'll return all the records.

*P.s: This is only a hack due to poor implementation by the developer.*

I have updated the value of the length parameter and it's returning all the data at once.

[https://getbiib.com/events/104/individual_rank.json?category_type_id=44&draw=5&columns[0][data]=rank&columns[0][name]=&columns[0][searchable]=true&columns[0][orderable]=false&columns[0][search][value]=&columns[0][search][regex]=false&columns[1][data]=display_name&columns[1][name]=&columns[1][searchable]=true&columns[1][orderable]=false&columns[1][search][value]=&columns[1][search][regex]=false&columns[2][data]=steps_count&columns[2][name]=&columns[2][searchable]=true&columns[2][orderable]=false&columns[2][search][value]=&columns[2][search][regex]=false&start=0&length=5000&search[value]=&search[regex]=false&_=1626618728875](https://getbiib.com/events/104/individual_rank.json?category_type_id=44&draw=5&columns%5B0%5D%5Bdata%5D=rank&columns%5B0%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B0%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B0%5D%5Borderable%5D=false&columns%5B0%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B0%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B1%5D%5Bdata%5D=display_name&columns%5B1%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B1%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B1%5D%5Borderable%5D=false&columns%5B1%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B1%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B2%5D%5Bdata%5D=steps_count&columns%5B2%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B2%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B2%5D%5Borderable%5D=false&columns%5B2%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B2%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&start=0&length=5000&search%5Bvalue%5D=&search%5Bregex%5D=false&_=1626618728875)

**P.s: I have reported the problem to the website owners as it's a bad idea to scrape someone else's work/contents.
Thank you.**